# Simple "UV Sphere" Normal Bake

Tags: normal-map

I've tried to bake a *Normal Map* for a simple *UV Sphere* that you can create from the *Mesh* section. So I added two meshes and I put a Subdiv modifier to one of them as the 'high poly' mesh and I left the other one as default 'low poly'.

The break result is an empty purple texture. #8080FF

I tried to change the *Extrusion* and *Max Ray Distance* values but nothing other than somewhere a yellowish color appeared.

Before this, I baked a more complex mesh and it worked well, but not on this simple basic mesh.
Did you ever experience something like that? Any solution?

Here is the Blend file if anyone need it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17SNvxde4crIhbfxExFiVILiXhz9uZy_2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure to understand, you are baking a completely smooth sphere with another one, what 3D details is it supposed to bake?

Comment: Hey! The high poly sphere has almost 32k vertices, the low poly has almost 500. So I suppose the difference should appear on the normal map, shouldn't it? Between the two meshes. there is a clearly visible difference in the viewport.

Comment: what are you expecting to see? If you bake a very smooth surface with a rather smooth surface, you won't see a lot of things.

Comment: I thought I should see the difference between the 2 mesh on the normal map after the bake, even if it's not that big. But if that's it, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: you can begin to see something if you have a lowpoly that is lower in polygons (or shade flat) but I'm not sure how you want to use the map it will give, maybe give more details

Comment: Yeah, it's true, if I turn it to flat shaded it's clearly visible on the normal map, but on smooth it's just a clear empty purple map. Same on a very low poly (26 vertices) sphere. I just hoped it'll give some plus details.